# MultiPageEditor tool bar contribution from the single page

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Another question concerning my XML-multipage editor. It is possible to contribute to eclipse's tool bar by means of `MultiPageEditorActionBarContributor`, to be precise by overriding `contributeToToolBar(IToolBarManager manager)` method and use the passed manager. In this case the contributed button(s) are visible from all pages of the editor.

```
@Override
public void contributeToToolBar(IToolBarManager manager)
{
    manager.add(new Separator());
    manager.add(updateTabsAction);
}
```

Is it possible to make some buttons visible olny if a specific page is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was quite easy to solve. Instead of overriding `contributeToToolBar` I added some code to `setActivePage` and worked with a `ToolBarManager` from there:

```
@Override
public void setActivePage(IEditorPart part)
{
    // ...skipped...

    IActionBars actionBars = getActionBars();
    if (actionBars != null)
    {

        // ...skipped...

        IToolBarManager toolBarManager = actionBars.getToolBarManager();
        if (part instanceof StructuredTextEditor)
        {
            toolBarManager.add(separator);
            toolBarManager.add(updateTabsAction);
        }
        else
        {
            toolBarManager.removeAll();
        }

        toolBarManager.update(true);  //This is important. Otherwise the
                                      //changes aren't applied to the toolbar.
        actionBars.updateActionBars();
    }
}
```